# How to go back to previous opened file in Goland?

Tags: goland

How to go back to previous opened file after clicking a function which leads to another file in JetBrains Goland?

The combinations `ctrl + alt + left arrow key` is not working for me.

Comment: You can try `Ctrl + Home + Alt + Left`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few different ways you can achieve this, depending on your needs:

- you can use the `Switcher` feature to quickly navigate between files, by pressing `Ctrl + Tab` or `Ctrl + Shift + Tab` (on all platforms)
- you can use the `Recent Files` feature that works via `Ctrl + E` on Windows/Linux and `⌘ + E` on macOS
- you can use the `Recent Locations` feature via `Ctrl + Shift + E` on Windows/Linux and `⌘ + Shift + E` on macOS
- you can use the browser like shortcuts for back and forth. For back they are: `Ctrl + Alt + Left Arrow` on Windows/Linux and  `⌘ + [` or `⌘ + Alt + Left Arrow` on macOS. For forward they are: `Ctrl + Alt + Right Arrow` on Windows/Linux and `⌘ + ]` or `⌘ + Alt + Right Arrow` on macOS

If `Ctrl + Alt + Left/Right Arrow` doesn't work for you, you can go to `Settings/Preferences | Keymap` and search for the `Back` action (under navigate). This should show you the keybinding for it. You can also try and find the action associated via shortcut using the magnifying glass next to the search box and pressing that shortcut. Make sure that your operating system/another application does not interfere with your keyboard shortcuts.

If you still have issues with this, it's best to open a support ticket on the official tracker at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/Go and attach the IDE logs via `Help | Compress Logs and Show in...`.